# How to take a full size and resolution photo from intent (Android 7)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent, android-7.1-nougat

It's been a while when I first tried to take a full size photo with an intent. I tried to scale the thumbnail, use the URI and I also tried the `FileProvider` and it didn't seem to work.
I'm sure I put all the `permissions`in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here's my code:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    public void openCamera(View view)
    {        
        photoName = "";

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0x5);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cameraCapture();
        }
    }

private void cameraCapture()
    {
        File image = null;
        try
        {
            File filePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "myfolder");
            image = new File(filePath + File.separator + "myimage.jpg");
            File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            if(!image.exists())image.createNewFile();
            currentImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {}

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.touchmultimedia.testpermessi.provider", image);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                File photoFile = new File(photoUri.getPath());
                if (photoFile != null && photoFile.exists())
                {
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoUri.getPath());
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
                    imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    photoName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

                    //deleteTemps(photoFile);

                    saved = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            switch(requestCode)
            {
                //Camera
                case 5:

                    cameraCapture();
                    break;

                //Write External Storage
                case 3:

                    saveImage();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I've read all the other examples, but none of them helped with my problem.

Thanks to everyone who can help me!

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "it didn't seem to work" means. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrating using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`. But bear in mind that not all Android camera apps that support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will work with a `content` `Uri`, like you get from `FileProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare With the `FileProvider` the application crushes, maybe because I made some mistakes, I followed the Android guides but they didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that "myfolder" is also created if it's not exist. `image.createNewFile()` will not create "myfolder" automatically for you.

Comment: I know, but I don't think the problem's there, because during debug I can take the folder URI, so I think it exists

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code from my app:

```
public void startCameraIntent(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent;
    int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    String deviceManufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String samsung = "samsung";
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M && deviceManufacturer.compareTo(samsung) != 0) {
        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Pls note the line with manufacturer check. Samsung uses different intent action for image capture since android M.